# Something like chainsuck on RD lower pulley after new crankset install?

Tags: shimano, crankset, derailleur-rear, sram, chain-tug

I just switched out a Shimano M5100 crankset for a SRAM GX Eagle crankset. I am using a KMC X11-EL chain. I cleaned the chain before installing it with the new crankset. My RD is a Shimano SLX 11-Speed. After installing the chain and running through the gears I noticed that the chain is getting caught up on the bottom jockey wheel of my RD. It isn't constant, it is intermittent. I thought maybe a few links were froze so I made sure to really lube the chain using Rock-n-Roll Gold chain lube.
I was experiencing some chain suck on the new SRAM chainring but that seems to be a lot better after lubing the chain although it's not perfect. Before installing my rear wheel (I also installed new brake rotors) I wiped all the grime off the RD, but didn't oil or lube it (maybe that's the reason for this issue, I have no idea). If anyone knows what might be going on and can help I would really appreciate it. I wasn't having this issue before with the Shimano crankset. Also I should mention when I have the RD clutch engaged there is barely an issue but when I have it disengaged then the chain really sticks on that bottom jockey wheel. I can provide a video of the issue if needed, but you'll have to help me out with how to post the video, as this is my first post on here.

Comment: Did you correctly adjust the chain length in accordance with your new crank set?

Comment: Frozen or stiff links aren't cured by lubrication.   Mark the point on the chain where the RD gets snagged and see if its consistent.  I have had chain links which flex one way but not the other, hard to spot.

Comment: As for posting video - upload it to youtube and copy-paste the link here.  That's easiest.

Comment: @Ender I actually didn't have to adjust the chain length, my old and new chainrings were/are 32T.

Comment: @Criggie I'll check the links. I will say that after letting the chain sit overnight it doesn't seem to have the problem anymore, atleast not when I'm actually riding. I'll have to check in the morning, Also i should mention this issue was happening when i was back pedaling and when i rode today i didn't back pedal at all so really for all i know i actually still am having the issue. I'll update this later tomorrow.